# How to mock vue router in a Vuex store test with Jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a vuex store like this:

```js
// store.js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import router from '../router' // this is a vuejs router

export const actions = {
  async load({ dispatch, commit }) {
    if (router.currentRoute.name === 'one-route') {
      dispatch('oneModule/oneAction', null, { root: true })
    } 
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  actions,
  ...
})
```

I would like to test it with Jest.

```js
// store.test.js
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import { actions } from './store'
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use(VueRouter)

describe('store tests', () => {
  let store, router, oneAction

  beforeEach(() => {
    oneAction = jest.fn()
    const modules = {
      oneModule: {
        namespaced: true,
        actions: { oneAction }
      }
    }
    store = new Vuex.Store({ actions, modules })
    router = new VueRouter({ routes: [{ name: 'one-route' }] })
  }

  test('call module action if one-route is selected', async () => {
    router.push({ name: 'one-route' })
    await store.dispatch('load')

    expect(oneAction).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
}
```

---

This makes the following error:

```
Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
```

What is the correct way to mock the router to make this test pass?
Thank you